# Are ultrasonic repeller devices painful for dogs?

Tags: dogs, mice, sound

I have mice in the apartment, and I am interested in using an ultrasonic repeller device. However, I read the following online:

> "Humans can hear sound at frequencies up to about 23,000 Hz (Hertz). Louisiana State University researchers report that mice and rats are sensitive to sound up to 60,000 and to about 76,000 Hz, respectively. However, common house pets such as cats and dogs can also hear ultrasonic frequencies. Cats can perceive sound up to about 64,000 Hz, and dogs perceive sounds up to 45,000 Hz. You should consider not using noise as a repellent for mice if you have pets."
>
> [Overview of Noise as a Mouse Repellant (eHow)](http://www.ehow.com/about_6571031_overview-noise-mouse-repellent.html)

While the gap between dogs (45,000 Hz) seems pretty far from the mouse level (up to 60,000 Hz), do commercially-available ultrasonic repellers fall in the "safe range" for dogs?

Comment: I plugged in two repellents yesterday. My three cats immediately ran to the device. I unplugged them while the cats were in the house.

Comment: They're painful for _me_ ...

Comment: I live in a duplex and my neighbor just started using them. I also have a skittish German Shepard,she seems to be pacing a lot more and is extra jumpy. Now diearrea has started as always when she uncomfortable. Can this affect her through a double fire wall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are referring to a [Riddex plug-in device](http://www.amazon.com/s/?keywords=riddex%20plug%20in).

I used to own one, and used it in my apartment where I lived with a dachshund. The instant I plugged the device in, a spider appeared on the wall from a vent, and crawled away down the hall.  This proved to me that the device actually did "something" to justify the manufacturer's claim.  My dog, a young dachshund with no known hearing issues (other than deliberately ignoring me when I ask him to do things), had no reaction to the device being plugged in.  To confirm he had no reaction, I plugged and unplugged the device multiple times, as this was a definite concern / deal-breaker for me if the dog was affected.  He did not react.

At a later date, I replaced the Riddex with a newer version; same dog, no reactions.  This same dog does react to a dog whistle and a behavioral device, neither of which I can hear.  The description of the Riddex device claims it does not interfere with pets.  I only have my own experience to back this up.

At some point, I stopped using the Riddex devices.  The first one died after a few years and I don't recall what happened with the second one.  I believe the devices become less efficient over time, but I have nothing to back up this claim.  I had not used Riddex in such a long time that I actually forgot I used to have one until I read this question.  As I live in a climate with many pests, I have hired an exterminator for regular maintenance.

Comment: There are several brands besides Riddex.

Answer (score 4):

I had these in every room in the house.  My dog began slowly to show signs of discomfort, teeth chattering and started to jump with movements around her.  It was getting worse.  I took her to the vet to check her teeth and also a full check over.  He found nothing.  Then one evening it occurred to me it maybe the plugs so I turned them all off.  It has been 3 weeks now and all the distressed symptoms have gone.  Coincidence? I don't think so.  Dogs do hear them and like humans , if they are sensitive it may distress them.

Comment: Oh and she lost lots of weight

Answer (score 1):

In are kitchen we have an electric fly killer to get rid of fly's. Recently our dog has being crying and acting as if he is scared. We tutned of all of any thing electrical like lights and flash lights but he seemed fine so turned back on everything and he went back to his bad behavior. Recently we were eating when when we heard are fly killer make a noise and soon we found that it was the problem, our dog was scared of it. We searched up what simtems happens and we soon found out that any sudden noises that are loud can give a dog a heart attack ( normally that older dog ) instantly we got rid of the DG ly killer. In future if you have dogs or cats in your house make sure you don't have an electric fly killer. ( the reason for them to have a heart attack is because they can hear much more than we can and if we think that something is loud they can hear it much note than we can!)